# Convert Grails 2.4.5 project latest Spring boot project

Tags: grails, spring-boot

We have been developing JSON based service on Grails with Spring-rest-security plugin, can anyone suggest how to move the project to Spring-Boot, not interested with Grails-3, which is also based on Spring boot even though. Looks for suggestions and recommendations!